# Hive query failed giving exception unexpected end of input stream

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, character-encoding, urlencode

Trying to build an external hive table from .gz log files present in HDFS in hive.
After running the query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name(att1 STRING,att3 STRING,att4 STRING,att5 STRING) row format serde "org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe" with serdeproperties ("ignore.malformed.json"="true") STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'hdfs:////hdfs_location/';
```

when i run

```
   select count(*) from table_name;
```

it fails by giving below stack trace:

> TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure
>   ) :
>   attempt_1534417036833_0016_1_00_000054_2:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
>   java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>     at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
>     at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
>   java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
>     ... 14 more

I tried looking into the content by validating the json.
Ran a ruby script to check for the contents:

```
require "zlib"
require "json"

path = "/home/test_directory/file.gz"
infile = open(path)
gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(infile)

gz.each_line do |line_content|      
    begin
        JSON.parse(line_content)  
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e  
        p "json parsing exception" + " -- " + line_content.strip
    rescue Exception => ex
        puts "An error of type #{ex.class} happened, message is #{ex.message}"
    end 
end
```

It gave me exception message for some lines in the file:

> An error of type Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError happened, message
>   is "\xC3" on US-ASCII

Tried modifying my query according to this: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/58548/processing-files-in-hive-using-native-non-utf8-cha.html
Modification was adding this line after creating external table:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='SJIS');
```

It dint worked.
P.S. : this is not empty files issue as discussed in some online forums, as I dont have blank files in hdfs.

What can i do about this, it seems like its some character encoding issue, but not able to get the solution.